# Input/Output on a file

Tags: java, io, output, writer, reader

I wrote a short program for one of my class and there is something that I just cannot figure out. So I am supposed to write 100 random integers on a file, read back the data and print the integers in increasing order. Everything works fine, but I don't see my final sorted list on the output file, anyone can see why?

Here is my code:

```
private final static int NUMBEROFRANDOM = 100;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Creating my file
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Question1.txt");

    // If it already exists, print a message and terminate program
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // Creating my PrintWriter object
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);

    // Creating 100 random numbers between 0 and 100 and printing them on the file
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFRANDOM; i++) {
        int number = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
        output.print(number + " ");
    }

    // Creating my Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    // Creating my array list to store the sorted list of 100 elements
    ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Reading the elements from the file and adding them into my array list
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        sortedList.add(input.nextInt());
    }

    //Sorting elements from array list
    Collections.sort(sortedList);

    // Printing the elements in increasing order
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(sortedList.get(i));
        output.print(sortedList.get(i));
    }

    // Closing my objects
    input.close();
    output.close();

}
```

Thank you very much, any help is very appreciated!

Comment: You need to close the output after you create the numbers.

Comment: I see someone beat me to it - my machine spent too long opening my IDE :)

Answer (score 1):

Your file is empty when you are reading it using `Scanner input = new Scanner(file);`

Use `output.flush()` to save your data after printing the values.

`output.close()` - will close your stream and you won't be able to store your sorted values.

```
// Creating 100 random numbers between 0 and 100 and printing them on the file
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFRANDOM; i++) {
    int number = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
    output.print(number + " ");
}

output.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the outputstream to get it to write to the file. You are doing this correctly the second time but not the first time.

Add:

```
output.close();
```

After:

```
// Creating 100 random numbers between 0 and 100 and printing them on the file
 for (int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFRANDOM; i++) {
     int number = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
    output.print(number + " ");
 }
//Here close the first output stream to get the data to the file.
output.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before below line of code, you need to `close` or `flush` to write your contents to your file.

```
output.close(); <--- you need to close here
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
```

Since, till above line of code, there was nothing written to the file. So, below code become useless

```
while (input.hasNext()) {  // nothing to read
        sortedList.add(input.nextInt()); //nothing added to List
    }

    //Sorting elements from array list
    Collections.sort(sortedList);  //nothing to sort

    // Printing the elements in increasing order
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) { 

        output.print(sortedList.get(i)); // won't execute this line
    }
```